# Do the f.input commands have to be nested within a f.inputs for ActiveAdmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, activeadmin, formtastic

When working on a form for ActiveAdmin that included some datepickers, I adapted some code from the [Datepicker](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/5-forms.md#datepicker) section:

```
ActiveAdmin.register AdminMessage do
  form do |f|
    f.input :message
    f.input :start_at,  as: :datepicker, datepicker_options: { min_date: "2013-10-8",        max_date: "+3D" }
  end
end
```

the HTML outputted included

```
      <div id="active_admin_content" class="without_sidebar">
        <div id="main_content_wrapper">
          <div id="main_content"><form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/admin/admin_messages" class="formtastic admin_message" id="new_admin_message" method="post" novalidate="novalidate"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="AbF7S3R+YIDruz770R2rz5YJubqlrZjx3BmhM5ZbjKI=" /></div><li class="datepicker input optional stringish" id="admin_message_start_at_input"><label class=" label" for="admin_message_start_at">Start at</label><input class="datepicker" id="admin_message_start_at" name="admin_message[start_at]" type="text" />

</li></form></div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

which didn't include anything for the `message` attribute of `AdminMessage`.

Nesting it within `f.inputs` fixed it.

```
ActiveAdmin.register AdminMessage do
  form do |f|
    f.inputs do
      f.input :message
      f.input :start_at,  as: :datepicker, datepicker_options: { min_date: "2013-10-8",        max_date: "+3D" }
    end
  end
end
```

gave

```
      <div id="active_admin_content" class="without_sidebar">
        <div id="main_content_wrapper">
          <div id="main_content"><form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/admin/admin_messages" class="formtastic admin_message" id="new_admin_message" method="post" novalidate="novalidate"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="AbF7S3R+YIDruz770R2rz5YJubqlrZjx3BmhM5ZbjKI=" /></div><fieldset class="inputs"><ol><li class="text input optional" id="admin_message_message_input"><label class=" label" for="admin_message_message">Message</label><textarea id="admin_message_message" name="admin_message[message]" rows="20">
</textarea>

</li><li class="datepicker input optional stringish" id="admin_message_start_at_input"><label class=" label" for="admin_message_start_at">Start at</label><input class="datepicker" id="admin_message_start_at" name="admin_message[start_at]" type="text" />

</li></ol></fieldset></form></div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Does `f.input` always have to be nested within `f.inputs` unless you're showing only one input? Or am I misinterpreting something?

There is additional documentation on the same page, but the initial documentation describes a DSL layered on top of formtastic, and I'd rather not use the DSL unless it adds something.

The documentation on Formtastic's [README](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic) doesn't explicitly say that `f.input` has to be nested within `f.inputs`, but in all of the examples, it's nested that way, unlike in the ActiveAdmin documentation.

I'm using Rails 3, activeadmin 0.6.3, and formtastic 2.2.1.

Comment: as per http://activeadmin.info/docs/5-forms.html it says that for default   `f.semantic_errors # shows errors on :base
  f.inputs          # builds an input field for every attribute
  f.actions         # adds the 'Submit' and 'Cancel' buttons`

Comment: you can try `active_admin_form_for resource do |f|
  inputs :title, :body
  actions
end`

Comment: @RajarshiDas how would I pass in options to the input for `start_at` if I used `active_admin_form_for resource do |f| [NEWLINE] inputs :title, :body [NEWLINE] actions [NEWLINE] end`?